# would it work to run scala with vaadin?

Tags: java, scala, vaadin

Im thinking of starting out with Scala and i got a question.

***In our Application layer we use Vaadin. Is it possible to work with Scala in a Vaadin project (using Eclipse) ? If yes, are there any nice books or tutorials? If no, why will it fail?***

Thx
Marthin

Comment: I've done this in the past, I used a Play! stack and integrated Vaadin page build in Scala without any issue !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vaadin will work flawlessly with any JVM language and Scala is no exception. I'm working on a Scala Vaadin project (sorry, nothing public yet) using the [Eclipse Scala IDE beta plugin](http://www.scala-ide.org/2011/05/scala-ide-beta-3-available/) and everything works just great.

You can find more info using Google, eg. [this recent article](http://blog.frankel.ch/mixing-vaadin-and-scala).

Comment: FYI, we're now seeking comments on what kind of Scala API would be good for Vaadin: http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/530126

Answer (score 6):

Scala and Java can be used together, so it's certainly possible.  I don't do Vaadin, so I can't help much, but [this article](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20Scala%20with%20Dynamic%20Web%20Projects%20and%20Vaadin%20in%20Eclipse) from Vaadin might help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple chat application written in Vaadin + Scala (open-source):

[vaadin-scala-chat](https://github.com/hrj/vaadin-scala-chat)

It can be useful as a starting template to build upon.